# Oracle Coherence CacheFactory.getCache() usage across threads

Tags: oracle-coherence

we have a multi-threaded application that uses Oracle Coherence 3.5 L1/L2 caching heavily (1k requests/second) where performance is critical...

1. do I need to synchronize access to `CacheFactory.getCache()`?
2. should I reuse the `NamedCache` result for subsequent requests?

currently its doing the following to minimize calls to the CacheFactory and synchronize access to it...

```
static ConcurrentHashMap<String, NamedCache> cacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NamedCache>();
protected static NamedCache getCache(String cacheName)
{
    NamedCache cache = cacheMap.get(cacheName);
    if (cache == null)
    {
        cache = CacheFactory.getCache(cacheName);
        cacheMap.put(cacheName, cache);
    }

    return cache;
}
```

UPDATE: after poking around a bit, this seems unnecessary since the Coherence APIs being supposed to be thread safe...seems like I could simplify to just this, correct?

```
protected static NamedCache getCache(String cacheName)
{
    return CacheFactory.getCache(cacheName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

after some performance testing...it seemed that reusing the NamedCache did prove slightly faster, so here is where I ended up...removed synchronized, used putIfAbsent() instead

```
protected static NamedCache getCache(String cacheName)
{
    NamedCache cache = cacheMap.get(cacheName);
    if (cache == null)
    {
        cache = CacheFactory.getCache(cacheName);
        NamedCache existing = cacheMap.putIfAbsent(cacheName, cache);
        if (existing != null)
            return existing;
    }

    return cache;
}
```